# Using Twitter api v1.1 Search/Tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

As Twitter switched off version 1.0 of their API on June 2013. I have to rewrite code for fetching tweets containing a specific hashtag by using new v1.1 api which needs OAuth. So, I have used (twitteroauth php library for twitter oauth). The website is https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.

require_once('twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');

```
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken("my-oauth-token", "my-oauth-token-secret");

$content = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline");
//$content = $connection->get("search/tweets.json?q=%23stack");
var_dump($content);
```

When I am doing:

```
$content = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline");
```

it fetches all tweets on my timeline properly, but when i do(required result)

```
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets.json?q=%23stack");
```

It doesn't show any results and gives output like following :

```
object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
  ["statuses"]=> array(0) { } ["search_metadata"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (8) { 
    ["completed_in"]=> float(0.008) 
    ["max_id"]=> float(3.6838148714793E+17) 
    ["max_id_str"]=> string(18) "368381487147933696" 
    ["query"]=> string(13) "%23stack.json" 
    ["refresh_url"]=> string(63) 
       "?since_id=368381487147933696&q=%23stack.json&include_entities=1" 
    ["count"]=> int(15) ["since_id"]=> int(0) ["since_id_str"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

this syntax works for me:

```
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets",
    array(
        'q' => "#luggatron", 
        'count' => 5
    )
);
```